# How to delete lines where certain pattern appears on the specific position

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I am having a file that looks like this:

```
PEBP1_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P30086  PDB; 1BD9; X-ray; 2.05 A; A/B=1-187.
                    PDB; 1BEH; X-ray; 1.75 A; A/B=1-187.
                    PDB; 2L7W; NMR; -; A=1-187.
                    PDB; 2QYQ; X-ray; 1.95 A; A=1-187.

PECA1_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P16284  PDB; 2KY5; NMR; -; A=686-738.
                    PDB; 5C14; X-ray; 2.80 A; A/B=28-229.
                    PDB; 5GEM; X-ray; 3.01 A; A/B=28-232.

PELO_HUMAN  Homo sapiens    Q9BRX2  PDB; 1X52; NMR; -; A=261-371.
                    PDB; 5EO3; X-ray; 2.60 A; A/B=265-385.
                    PDB; 5LZW; EM; 3.53 A; ii=1-385.
                    PDB; 5LZX; EM; 3.67 A; ii=1-385.
                    PDB; 5LZY; EM; 3.99 A; ii=1-385.
                    PDB; 5LZZ; EM; 3.47 A; ii=1-385.
```

From this file I want to match all `EM;` elements that are found just after `PDB; (four letter code); EM;`. So under this column either `X-ray;`, `NMR;` or `EM;` can be found. For those lines that have `EM;` remove them. Is there some bash command that I can use to match these elements and remove these lines?

Importantly when matching it put the space before `EM`, so match it with space, like `EM;`.

Expected result is:

```
PEBP1_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P30086  PDB; 1BD9; X-ray; 2.05 A; A/B=1-187.
                    PDB; 1BEH; X-ray; 1.75 A; A/B=1-187.
                    PDB; 2L7W; NMR; -; A=1-187.
                    PDB; 2QYQ; X-ray; 1.95 A; A=1-187.

PECA1_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P16284  PDB; 2KY5; NMR; -; A=686-738.
                    PDB; 5C14; X-ray; 2.80 A; A/B=28-229.
                    PDB; 5GEM; X-ray; 3.01 A; A/B=28-232.

PELO_HUMAN  Homo sapiens    Q9BRX2  PDB; 1X52; NMR; -; A=261-371.
                    PDB; 5EO3; X-ray; 2.60 A; A/B=265-385.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` can do that:

```bsh
awk '{if(!($1=="PDB;"&&$3=="EM;")){print}}' <yourfile
```

This tests if the first column (by default whitespaces are taken as the delimiter) of the current line is `PDB;` and the third column is `EM;` and prints the line only if not both are true.

#### Output

```bsh
$ awk '{if(!($1=="PDB;"&&$3=="EM;")){print}}' <test
PEBP1_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P30086  PDB; 1BD9; X-ray; 2.05 A; A/B=1-187.
                    PDB; 1BEH; X-ray; 1.75 A; A/B=1-187.
                    PDB; 2L7W; NMR; -; A=1-187.
                    PDB; 2QYQ; X-ray; 1.95 A; A=1-187.

PECA1_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P16284  PDB; 2KY5; NMR; -; A=686-738.
                    PDB; 5C14; X-ray; 2.80 A; A/B=28-229.
                    PDB; 5GEM; X-ray; 3.01 A; A/B=28-232.

PELO_HUMAN  Homo sapiens    Q9BRX2  PDB; 1X52; NMR; -; A=261-371.
                    PDB; 5EO3; X-ray; 2.60 A; A/B=265-385.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this - using perl's *paragraph mode*:

```
$ perl -F'\n' -00le 'print join "\n", grep { !/PDB; ....; EM;/ } @F' file
PEBP1_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P30086  PDB; 1BD9; X-ray; 2.05 A; A/B=1-187.
                    PDB; 1BEH; X-ray; 1.75 A; A/B=1-187.
                    PDB; 2L7W; NMR; -; A=1-187.
                    PDB; 2QYQ; X-ray; 1.95 A; A=1-187.

PECA1_HUMAN Homo sapiens    P16284  PDB; 2KY5; NMR; -; A=686-738.
                    PDB; 5C14; X-ray; 2.80 A; A/B=28-229.
                    PDB; 5GEM; X-ray; 3.01 A; A/B=28-232.

PELO_HUMAN  Homo sapiens    Q9BRX2  PDB; 1X52; NMR; -; A=261-371.
                    PDB; 5EO3; X-ray; 2.60 A; A/B=265-385.
```